# Hyperbola is path connected $(x>0)$

Tags: general-topology

Please tell me if this is a right way to prove that hyperbola is path connected $(x>0)$

Define $f:(0,\pi/2)\mapsto\mathbb{R}^2$ as $f(t)=(\sec(t),\tan(t))$. Then as $f$ is continuous and $(0,\pi/2)$ is path connected and continuous image of path connected set is path connceted$\Rightarrow$ hyperbola is path connected.

Is there another way of proving this? Thank you.

Comment: Assuming you meant the positive branch of the hyperbola $xy = 1$, did you mean $(\cot(t),\tan(t))$? Other than that, the reasoning you used to clinch the result is fine.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention what kind of hyperbola, it is $x^2-y^2=1$

Comment: Then you didn't parametrize it correctly. For the branch with $x > 0$, You're only getting the top half.

Comment: @quasi I intend to prove the right half is path connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is basically OK, but needs a minor tweak . . .

The branch of the hyperbola $x^2 - y^2 = 1$ with $x > 0$ is the continuous image of the open interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ using the function

$$f:(-\pi/2,\pi/2)\to\mathbb{R}^2$$

$$\text{defined by}$$

$$f(t)=(\sec(t),\tan(t))$$

With that minor change, your reasoning works well to finish it.